# Visual Studio: SSRS how to avoid duplicate textbox names on copying table

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having an annoying problem, when ever I copy a table and paste the table in the same report almost all the textboxes will be named similarly **textbox1** and the copy: **Textbox1**

This causes the report to show an error when starting to debug and I have to rename every "dublicate". Is there any way around this?

Almost as annoying thing is also that on copying CDbl() becomes

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel.ExpressionParser.VBFunctions.CDbl()
```

And this causes an error

[image]

[image]

### Edit

The error caused by naming.

Comment: show us the image, which displays same name of textbox. Because it never set same name.

Comment: -pedram It is not exactly the same name, it capitalizes the first letter, but still when you run it, you get an error

Comment: Which error comes? please show us

Comment: I will add it the next time I run in to it. I remamed the all of the boxes allready. P.S It only effects those textboxes with functions, blanks are ok, to have similar names. And no I'm not using textbox references in the functions. All functions are calculated with DataSet references

Comment: – pedram  Edited the error I receive. This is in another report that I´m working on, but same error as soon as I copied and added the table

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug. I think:

- SSRS is not case-sensitive, while visual studio is.
- <s>Problem happens when the report created in older VS is opened in newer VS with different naming convention.</s>

Workaround:

- check which format the new duplicate names are in
- **before copying**, manually rename everything to that format.
  For example, if your textBox224 is copied as TextBox134, then rename each textBox*** to TextBox***. (Obviously use "search and replace").

Comment: The problem occurs also in the older version. I´m using both 2008/2012 and can confirm that it occurs also in 2008 version.

Comment: Then my reasoning was wrong, updated the question. Or perhaps one of the VS service packs changed naming convention? The suggested workaround should still work.